# Wubi: How do I find the Windows partition from Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, windows, wubi, files, transfer

I ran the Wubi installer, and now I have both Windows 7 professional and Ubuntu on my laptop. When I run the laptop with Ubuntu, I cannot find any of the files from Windows, nor can I find the Windows partition.

Comment: Does the windows partition appear on Nautilus on the left side bar?  Try clicking there (it might ask you for your user password to mount the partition)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/)

> How do I access the Windows drives?
>
> The Windows partition where you installed Wubi is available as /host 
>   within Ubuntu (Places > Computer > File System > Host) All the other
>   partitions will be available under Places > Removable Media