# Can Wubi install access entire Windows partition?

Tags: 12.10, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi: How do I find the Windows partition from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158439/wubi-how-do-i-find-the-windows-partition-from-ubuntu)

I've installed Ubuntu by Wubi on C:. Is there a way to access rest of the C drive data from within Ubuntu? I see that it can access other partitions (D: where I have most of my data).

Comment: Check out the [Wubi FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_access_the_Windows_drives.3F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Host partition is accessible from /host